# Is there a way to store std::atomic, inside a struct, inside an std::pair?

Tags: c++, struct, c++17, std-pair, stdatomic

VS2017 provides the following error when I try to add a `std::atomic` to a struct stored in an `std::pair` (inside an `std::unordered_map`):

```
error C2660: 'std::pair<uint32_t,AtomicStruct>::pair': function does not take 2 arguments
```

I've simplified the issue down to the following code (removing the std::unordered_map for clarity/focus):

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout
#include <utility>  // std::pair
#include <atomic>   // std::atomic

struct AtomicStruct
{
    std::atomic_uint32_t a;

    // associated data goes here...
};

using AtomicPair = std::pair<uint32_t, AtomicStruct>;

int main()
{
    AtomicStruct as = { 1 };                    // This initializer works just fine
    std::cout << "as: " << as.a << std::endl;   // Outputs "as: 1" as expected

    AtomicPair pr1(0, as);                      // error C2660
    AtomicPair pr2(0, { 1 });                   // error C2660

    return 0;
}
```

From what I've pieced together so far:

- `std::atomic` deletes the copy-constructor.
- `std::pair`'s template checks for the parameters being `is_copy_constructible`, when the parameters specify the `first` and `second` of the std::pair.
- Because the `std::atomic`, or second, parameter isn't `is_copy_constructible`, the constructor definition isn't created.
- The compiler then falls back to the `std::pair(const std::pair&) = default` copy constructor, which fails because the number of parameters is incorrect (two, instead of one), as well as the type is wrong.

If I remove the `std::atomic` from the struct, I can put it directly into a `std::pair`

```
std::pair<uint32_t, std::atomic_uint32_t> pr3(0, 1);    // Works!
```

I thought maybe the initializer was being used for construction too early, and also tried:

```
AtomicPair pr4(0, { { 1 } });  // error C2660
```

Maybe I'm missing something obvious... Does anyone know a way to store structs containing `std::atomic`s in a `std::pair`?

Comment: Use the tuple constructor for `pair`, it allows constructing non-move able non-copyable `pair`s.

Comment: Is `AtomicStruct` meant to be an aggregate?

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, that was my original intent, though it's not a hard requirement.

Comment: Sorry, don't have time for answer but see working code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e24130fe7678c49

Comment: If you have an answer to your question, please post it as such and accept it. Otherwise your question will linger as unanswered. Note: it is perfectly fine to write and accept answers to your own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since an answer, via link, was given in the comments, and I don't know how long that will live, I'm copy/pasting the crucial bits of the answer/example provided by @NathanOliver, in case someone else needs the answer.

As @Nichol_Bolas pointed out, my initial intent was for `AtomicStruct` to be an aggregate; if anyone knows of a way to improve upon the answer below and keep `AtomicStruct` as an aggregate, I'm open to suggestions.

```
struct AtomicStruct
{
    std::atomic_uint32_t a;
    AtomicStruct(uint32_t a) : a(a) {}
    // associated data goes here...
};

int main()
{
    //... 
    AtomicPair pr1{std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(0), std::forward_as_tuple(1)};
    //...
}
```